# Using a loop in filter

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am quite new to R. Using dplyr and filter, I want to select records for which a list of variables !=NA.

```
df %>% filter (var1 != "NA" | var2 != "NA" | var3 != "NA" )
```

The problem is that I have 85 such variables (ending with HR). So I have extracted them and put them in a vector.

```
hr_variables <- grep("HR$", names(ssc), value=TRUE)
```

I would like to make a loop that will fetch hr_variable and then filter() by applying the OR condition to each element.
Is this possible in R?

Comment: Do you have `NA` as character or else use `is.na`  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  Did you meant the row selected do not have NA in all the HR variables or is the logic different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `base R` to do this more easily

```
ssc[!rowSums(is.na(ssc[hr_variables])),]
#  col1_HR col2_HR      col3
#2       1       3 0.5365853
#3       2       4 0.4196231
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
ssc %>% 
   select_(.dots = hr_variables) %>%
   map(~is.na(.)) %>% 
   reduce(`|`) %>%
    `!` %>% 
   extract(ssc, .,)
```

Or with `complete.cases`

```
ssc %>% 
     select_(.dots = hr_variables) %>% 
     complete.cases(.) %>% 
     extract(ssc, ., )
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
ssc <- data.frame(col1_HR = c(NA, 1, 2, 3), col2_HR = c(NA, 3, 4, NA), col3 = rnorm(4))
```

Comment: I have slightly changed your first suggestion, thank you very much:   `studies_hr <- (rowSums(!is.na(ssc[,hr_variables])))>0
ssc_hr <- ssc [studies_hr, ]`